# Regular expression to validate phone number

Tags: regex

I got this regular expression for validating phone number

```
/^(\+)?[\d\s\-\(\)]+$/
```

This validates most of the phone numbers except -

```
+01 (555 236 4960
```

here the closing brace is missing but it does not validate this.
What should be changed in the existing regex so that it matches the closing brace as well

Comment: Did you google for it, you will get answer (Similar questions has been asked multiple times on this forum)?

Comment: it works https://regex101.com/r/xD4nB1/1

Comment: That regex will also match `-`. [Example](http://regexr.com/3b83r)

Comment: +01 (555 236 4960 should not be matched with the above regex as the closing parenthesis is missing. So ideally i want a regex with must throw an error if the closing parenthesis is missing.